# How to put an overlaying Image In HTML/SCSS

Tags: html, css, sass

[image: Example of how I want it]

1st step: `background-size: cover;`

2nd step: `background-size: contain; background-repeat: no-repeat;`

3rd step is how I need it: first background image is `cover` and the second is an overlay with `no-repeat`

---

At this point my Html contains a `div`:
`<div class="news" data-background="@item.ImageUrl">`

I've tried a few things but I always can only add one picture to it and not a 2nd copy of itself.

How can I get a result as the far-right example on the image?

Some extra information about the SCSS-file

```
.vertical .news {
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 18px;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-color: $DarkTurquoise;
    max-height: 85vh;
    height: 80vh;
    width: 30vw;
    margin-bottom: 3vw;
    margin-right: 1vw;
    margin-left: 1vw;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have an outer-container with a background-image, an inner-container with `backdrop-filter: blur(5px)` and an `img` inside the inner-container which is limited to the width of the outer-container:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  background: url("http://lowcadence.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/josiahrides.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
}

.image {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://lowcadence.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/josiahrides.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

**Note**: `backdrop-filter` isn't supported in Firefox.